# Verizon FIOS Quantum Gateway replacement power supply?

Tags: router, power-supply

We have Verizon service with a FIOS Quantum Gateway router model FIOS-G1100. The power wart is going bad and we need to replace it. On occasion the device looses power. Putting a meter on the barrel connector shows no potential. Beating the power wart on the floor restores the connection.

According to [Fios Quantum Gateway USER GUIDE](https://www.verizon.com/cs/groups/public/documents/adacct/fqgrouter-userguide.pdf), p 210, the power supply is 12V DC 3.0A. However it does not list a part number or specification for the barrel connector.

What is the part number for the power supply? Or, what is the specification on the barrel connector.

(The power wart is so fragile I don't want to unplug it for fear it will die completely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [quick search for FIOS-G1100 *power adaptor*](https://www.bing.com/search?q=power%20adapter%20for%20fios%20g1100&qs=RI&pq=fios-g1100%20power%20&sk=SC1&sc=3-17&cvid=89061528E03E45AFAFA5432017FA3FE8&FORM=QBRE&sp=2) suggests its a KSAS0361200300HU made by ktech power. There's an [amazon link here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01I0A3HS8). Its designed for that model - I can't quite tell what the barrel size is and you can tell the barrel polarity from the amazon image as being center positive, if you wanted to get an equivilent replacement